# Forcing latex to write equations on one line

Tags: equations

I was trying to write the following in latex: "we already proved that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R},f(x)<1$", unfortunately I obtained "f(x)" on a line and "<1" on the next line.

Is there any command or  a way so that it's possible to force latex to write the equation on a line ?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I'm sure this has been answered before.  Line breaking will be better if you enter this math in two pieces: `$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, ${f(x)<1$`.  If that still breaks before the `<1`, put the second part in an `\mbox`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - You beat me to exactly this comment by about 30 seconds. :-)

Comment: why not only using \mbox? (without 2 pieces)

Comment: I read that this command prevent line breaks whence used, hence a longer line

Comment: Because there is an allowable break point between the two pieces. Remember, in math mode latex are not allowed to linebreak after comma, using the two pieces gets the comma in text mode (line break allowed) and let's us use the proper spacing between comma and `f(x)`. Once experienced, one an see from the pdf when authors have used two pieces and when they haven't.

Comment: You mention that you get a line break between `f(x)` and `<`. Please show the code that gives rise to this phenomenon. The reason I make this request is that no matter how hard I try, I can only generate a line break after, but not before, the `<` symbol. Thanks.

Comment: `We already proved that, for all $x\in\nolinebreak\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)<\nolinebreak 1$.` Chances are that you don't even need `\nolinebreak`. If you definitely want no line break after relation symbols, add `\relpenalty=10000` in your document preamble.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the following four instances of two lines of text and math, where I've highlighted the instances of `f(x)<1` in green:

[image]

- The first instance replicates what the OP reports, while using the single, long-ish instance of inline math mode, *viz.*, `$\forall x \in \mathbb{R},f(x)<1$`. (Well, it's only *almost* a replica, as I managed to generate a line break after, *but not before*, the `<` symbol, no matter how hard I tried.) Clearly, having `1` dangle off on the second line isn't optimal from a typographic point of view. The line break after `<` happens because (a) TeX tries very, hard to avoid creating overfull lines and (b) line breaks are, in fact, permissible after objects of type `math-rel` (such as `<`) while in inline math mode.
- The second instance breaks up `$\forall x \in \mathbb{R},f(x)<1$` into `$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)<1$`. This is legitimate because the particles `\forall x \in \mathbb{R}` and `f(x)<1` constitute separate subformulas and the intervening `,` (comma) belongs, syntactically speaking, to the sentence structure and not to either subformula. While making this change succeeds in making the space after the comma a regular inter-word space, it does *not succeed* in keeping `f(x)<1` all on one line. Oh well.
- The third instance encases `f(x)<1` in an `\mbox` wrapper, i.e., `$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, \mbox{$f(x)<1$}`. Unsurprisingly, this change does succeed in keeping the expression `f(x)<1` on one line. However, it does so at the considerable typographic expense of making the interword spaces and the whitespace around `\in` unusually large, making for a rather loose and untidy appearance.
- What to do if you dislike looseness and untidiness? You could consider rewriting and, in particular, *shortening*, some of the material that precedes the inline formulas on line 1. For instance, replacing "we already proved" with "we have shown" (or, if you prefer, "we have proved") -- omitting the 7-letter word "already" is legitimate because of the switch from past to perfect tense -- succeeds brilliantly in keeping both subformulas all on one line.

Moral of the story: Keep your inline formulas short, and don't hesitate to re-write your sentences in order to avoid undesirable line breaks. Oh, and don't undertake such touch-up exercise until you're confident you're just about done with your paper, as otherwise further changes to the text and math may render your touch-up work irrelevant.

---

Finally, the LaTeX code that generated the screenshot posted above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb} % for '\mathbb' macro
\begin{document}
\hspace{5mm}\dots to write the following in latex: we 
already proved that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, f(x)<1$, 
unfortunately \dots

\medskip
\hspace{5mm}\dots to write the following in latex: we 
already proved that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)<1$, 
unfortunately \dots

\medskip
\hspace{5mm}\dots to write the following in latex: we 
already proved that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, \mbox{$f(x)<1$}, 
unfortunately \dots

\medskip
\hspace{5mm}\dots to write the following in latex: we 
have shown that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)<1$, 
unfortunately \dots

\end{document}
```